# Java - GridLayout Problems

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

I am creating a `JScrollPane` in which I have a panel with a `GridLayout`. What I need is four cells, two of which contain text, and the other two of which are populated with check boxes.

I then need to be able to resize the grid with the check boxes.

I've tried all sorts of things, but can't seem to get it to act as I'm wanting.

Could someone please offer an example of a `GridBagLayout` which creates grids of unequal sizes, populated dynamically? Any examples or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code. Please post SSCCE.

Comment: *"I then need to be able to resize the grid with the check boxes."*  Why?

Comment: Andrew ,  I meant I need grid of unequal sizes

Comment: @user1903199 `I then need to be able to resize the grid with the check boxes.` works for me, nobody knows whats wrong from poor description, for better help sooner post and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: thanks for the help i was able to find the solution through gridBagLayout